# imageJ macro avi video batch conversion

Tags: macros, batch-processing, imagej, avi

I'm trying to batch convert .avi files using imageJ macro.

```bs
dir1 = getDirectory("path/source"); 
dir2 = getDirectory("path/target"); 
list = getFileList(dir1); 
setBatchMode(true); 
for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) { 
  showProgress(i+1, list.length); 
  if(endsWith(list[i],".avi")) 
  run("AVI...", "open=["+dir1+list[i]+"]"); 
  else
  saveAs(format, dir2+list[i]); 
  close(); 
}
```

But it asks to choose files manually with a dialog box and doesn't process automatically. Could anyone help with this? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Currently in your macro, you are _either_ **opening** an AVI file (if the name ends with 'avi') _or_ **saving** the current image (whatever it will be at runtime) as the current file name... I figure there might be some misconception here. You also might get more help when asking on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily accomplish your goal using the *Process ▶ Batch ▶ Macro...* command.

See the [Batch Processing page](http://imagej.net/Batch) on the ImageJ wiki for details.

Comment: This seems to work for standard image formats, but @Joseph asked about video data (avi). The dropdown in the batch processing window doesn't allow for avi as output format. Do you know any workarounds for this?

Comment: @dopexxx Good point. I assumed based on the question above that the _input_ format was AVI, but output format was probably something else. If you need to convert to a format not on the hardcoded list of _Process > Batch > Macro..._ or _Process > Batch > Convert..._, then I recommend starting from a script template such as one of the _Templates > ImageJ 1.x > Examples > Process Folder_ scripts. We are also on the cusp of releasing a new Batch button feature of the ImageJ search bar and [Script Editor](https://imagej.net/Script_Editor), so you can execute commands across all files in a folder.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :) Just to add for newbies, you need to open a new script via *File > New > Script* before you can do *Templates > ImageJ 1.x* ...